# getSelection is not working for an image in Chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe, webkit, wysiwyg, getselection

In my site I am using a WYSIWYG editor that uses an iframe.

When I select a text with double click in order to add a link to it, in Chrome, Safari and Firefox the selected text is the right one and the link is added.

However, when I click an image instead, the selection is done only in Firefox. Chrome and Safari have an empty selection and in order to select the image and add a link on it, I have to drag the mouse over it, like a manual select.

My code is:

```
 var sel = parent.document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document.getSelection();

 if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt (0);
    var docFragment = range.cloneContents ();
    var tmpDiv = document.createElement ("div");
    tmpDiv.appendChild (docFragment);
    selHTML = tmpDiv.innerHTML;
 }

 if (selHTML != '') {
     parent.document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document.execCommand(id,false,value);
 }
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

I change the code to that one according to @Tim suggestions:

```
 var iframeWin = parent.document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow;
 var iframeDoc = iframeWin.document;
 var sel = iframeWin.getSelection();
 var range = iframeDoc.createRange();
 var referenceNode = document.getElementsByTagName("img").item(0);
 range.selectNode(referenceNode);

 sel.removeAllRanges();
 sel.addRange(range);
parent.document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document.execCommand(id,false,value);
```

But still not works. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this manually using the `dblclick` event, but beware of breaking the regular image resize handles you get in non-WebKit browsers.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x49hv/3/

Code:

```
var iframeWin = parent.document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow;
var iframeDoc = iframeWin.document;

// Prevent errors in IE < 9, which does not support DOM Range and Selection
if (iframeWin.getSelection && iframeDoc.createRange) {
    iframeDoc.ondblclick = function(e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
            var sel = iframeWin.getSelection();
            var range = iframeDoc.createRange();
            range.selectNode(e.target);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is not really working. On click after adding the link, what really happens is to add a link above the image as text, and not on the image.

Comment: @novellino: Does it actually select the image before the link creation fails?

Comment: your example works also for me. will check the rest of my code and see if could be something else wrong.

Comment: Well I cannot use the ondblclick event. This code is i a function which is called as long as I am going to add the link. So what I need only is the selected image. And if I took the if out, I cannot set the selectNode.

Comment: @novellino: I don't quite understand what the situation is then.

Comment: I updated my question. So now you can see the code I am using according to your comments, but still is not working.